# How to send emojis using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my webpage, I have an input method and a button which opens a popup with smiles. When a user taps a smile once, the input value is changed to 'current value' + ':smile1:', for example. However, I have about 28 smile icons and this way to send emojis is a little bit difficult. How can I make this process easier? Because after this, I'll need to parse all 28 smiles and check if the input value equals one of them.

My popup:

```
<div class="smile-popuptext" id="smPopup">
<div class="smile1"></div>
<div class="smile2"></div>
<div class="smile3"></div>
//.....and other 25 divs
</div>
```

My function that sends the smile:

```
    $('.smile1').on('click', function () {
    var message = $('#message').val() + ' :smile1:';
    $('#message').val(message);
});
```

Comment: decyphring your Question I can assume your classes are not correct. Can you fix your own code and show a [mcve]?

Comment: check out emojieone http://emojione.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With no changes in your markup:

```js
$('#smPopup div[class^="smile"]').on('click', function () {
    var message = $('#message').val() + ' :' + this.className + ':';
    $('#message').val(message);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="smile-popuptext" id="smPopup">
    <div class="smile1">smile 1</div>
    <div class="smile2">smile 2</div>
    <div class="smile3">smile 3</div>
</div>

<textarea id="message"></textarea>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep it!

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend giving all the buttons a single class and giving them unique id's.

So something like this:

```
<div class="smile-popuptext" id="smPopup">
<div class="smile" id="smile1"></div>
<div class="smile" id="smile2"></div>
<div class="smile" id="smile3"></div>
//.....and other 25 divs
</div>
```

Then:

```
$('.smile').on('click', function () {
  var message = $('#message').val() + ' :' + this.id + ':';
  $('#message').val(message);
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ugstuzpn/1/)

Comment: Those classes are different, each class has a different options. But thanks, I've been looking for something like this.

Comment: You should be able to do the same things with id in your CSS that you're doing with your class.  Making a new class for each individual emoji might be unnecessary (although I suppose it depends on the context).

Answer (score 2):

You could bind an EventListener on the container and defining the value as a `data` attribute:

```js
var container = document.querySelector('.smile-popuptext');
container.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  var target = event.target;
  var emoji = target.getAttribute('data-emoji');
  if(emoji) {
     console.log('clicked', [':', emoji, ':'].join(''));
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="smile-popuptext" id="smPopup">
  <div class="sm1" data-emoji="smile1">1</div>
  <div class="sm2" data-emoji="smile2">2</div>
  <div class="sm3" data-emoji="smile3">3</div>
</div>
```